# System.IO.FileLoadException : The given assembly name or codebase was invalid

Tags: .net, akka.net

Hi has anyone had their actorsystem crash with a bad config string? I was given

```
System.IO.FileLoadException : The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
```

so it seems that it cannot resolve a typename using my config string. here it is:

```
akka {
loglevel=WARNING,
loggers=[""
Akka.Logger.Serilog.SerilogLogger,
Akka.Logger.Serilog,
Akka.TestKit.TestEventListener,
Akka.TestKit""]}
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong since serilog and testkit all are installed.

[Here is the full stack trace.](https://pastebin.com/a9KLaLyz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`akka.loggers` configuration takes a list of types described with [Fully Qualified Type Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names), eg. *Akka.Logger.Serilog.SerilogLogger,
Akka.Logger.Serilog*. See, that there's only one `,` in that name.

In your configuration, you specified two fully qualified type names, you haven't separated them, so they are read as a single name with 3 `,` in it, which is invalid for a FQTN. Simply separate those two types:

```
akka {
    loggers = [
        "Akka.Logger.Serilog.SerilogLogger, Akka.Logger.Serilog",
        "Akka.TestKit.TestEventListener, Akka.TestKit"
    ]
}
```